# IOS Swift - Window size shrinks when running in iphone 5s

Tags: iphone, swift, window, size

[image]

This happens when I run in the iphone 5s. Tried everything I know including checking LaunchImage s. Their resolution are according to apples standards.

In simulator no problems.

Anyone have any solution for this?

Iphone 5s - os 9.2.1
Xcode 7.2.1

Comment: Are you using storyboard or create window manually?

Comment: You need to set splash screen for your app. Otherwise it will take 3.5 screen size. Just set the splash screen and you will be done.

Comment: you mean launch screen right?

Comment: @ShemilHashan Yes exactly..Can you please confirm your splash screen image size.

Comment: Thanks,it worked. Please post it as an answer. I can upvote + accept as answer.

Comment: @ShemilHashan Can you please explain your resolution so any body helps this.

Comment: Adding the splash screen worked. If you can post your comment as an answer, I can accept it is as answer her so anyone else having the problem will find the answer easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a Launch Screen fixes this. answer was given by Nimit Parekh